# Problem with computing loss in feed forward NN

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to create a simple feed forward NN, but when computing the loss it is returning NaN. Any advice?

Here is my architecture:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,k):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(k, 5) # 1st hidden layer takes an input of size k
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 3) # Output layer has a size of 3 neurons
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)) # ReLu activation for 1st hidden layer
        x = F.softmax(self.fc2(x), dim=1) # Softmax activation for output layer
        return x

model = Net(300) # Create model for an embedding of size k=300
```

Here is my optimizer and loss fn:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001) 
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

I was running a check over a single epoch to see what was happening and this is what happened:

```
y_pred = model(x_train) # Create model using training data
loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train) # Compute loss on training data

print(y_pred)
print(y_train)
print(loss_fn(y_pred, y_train))
```

The printing returns the following output:

```
tensor([[0.3597, 0.2954, 0.3449],         [0.3615, 0.2955, 0.3430],         [0.3600, 0.2954, 0.3446],         ...,         [0.3590, 0.2953, 0.3457],         [0.3603, 0.2955, 0.3442],         [0.3605, 0.2955, 0.3441]], grad_fn=<SoftmaxBackward>) 
tensor([0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 2, 0]) 
tensor(nan, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

My Tensors are of length 300 as I am passing in word embeddings with 300 dimensions.

Comment: Hello ! The problem most likely comes from your data. You should look for NaN in your dataset. By the way, if you use `crossentropyloss` then you don't need the softmax layer at the end of your model

Comment: @trialNerror Is there any way you could show me the code of how to change this? I have checked for NaN and there are some instances, how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you set requires_grad = true on fc1 and fc2 before computing the loss?

Comment: read this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html